# How Java (Java8) fix WhiteHat "Improper Certificate Validation" (CWE-295) security vulnerability

Tags: security

We use the WhiteHat Source scanner to scan our source code. The tool finds out 'Improper Certificate Validation' (CWE-295) security issue at 2 methods. Is it a True Positive security issue? If yes, how could we fix it in Java 8, do we have a solution to fix issue like this? Thank you very much.

- public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) --> security vuln
- public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) --> security vuln

```
// http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/
public class JavaCertificationUtils {

    private static final SanitizedLogger LOG = new SanitizedLogger(JavaCertificationUtils.class);

    public static void javaTrustAllCerts() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }};

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

            // Create all-trusting host name verifier
            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting host verifier
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Java Certificate All Certs Exception.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing does two things:

1. It disables the TLS certificate chain validation (with `trustAllCerts`).
2. And than it disables the host name verification (with `allHostsValid`).

How to fix this? First of all - remove the code. All of it. The exact lines that seem to do the damage are:

```
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

You will probably notice (with a probability of 90%), that the code will stop working. This might be due to different reasons.

1. You are trying to connect to a service that uses a self signed certificate (might be a reason someone made a hack like this in the first place). The service would need to fix this.
2. You don't have all necessary certificates in the trust store to verify the trust chain. In this case you would need to extend your trust store and add the necessary Root CA certificates.
3. You connect over a SSH tunnel to a TLS secured service. Once you translate a proper domain name to a localhost: the TLS hostname validation will fail.
4. Something else will fail.

Let us know what the error is then.